# IE9 rendering issues with jquery hide/show

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have some lightbox-style pop-up coded in jQuery. It works in every decent browser, except IE9 (if considered a decent browser). It works fine if you click it: the pop-up opens, nothing unusual. However, as soon as you move your cursor, everything starts flickering, disappearing or whatever IE9 is capable of doing to destroy functionality.

I have no idea how this happens (also because it doesn't happen in IE8). I've given all elements I'm using proper positions and z-indexes. The problem is not the black screen overlay (which is just a div with a transparent background, z-index well below the centered content), I tested that already by completely removing that element from the code.

Here's the code I use to hide/show the div:

```
    //open popup
$(".pop").click(function(){
    $refselector = "." + $(this).attr("rel")
    $($refselector).fadeIn(500);
    $(".ui-overlay").fadeIn(50);
positionPopup();
});  

//close popup
$(".close").click(function(){
    $(".overlay-form").fadeOut(500);
    $(".ui-overlay").fadeOut(500);
});

//close popup by clicking outside the box
$(".ui-overlay").click(function(){
    $(".overlay-form").fadeOut(500);
    $(".ui-overlay").fadeOut(500);
});
```

If you want to see it in action: http://www.puurtrainingen.nl/referenties and click any of the four boxes.

If anyone ever encountered problems like this and knows the solution: your help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: You did now fix id, did you? I just wanted to see the problem in action, to see how it relates to mine with IE9 (Don't laugh we have business requirements to support it). Would you mind posting the original page somewhere for reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.page-item`'s `overflow: hidden` caused the problem.

You can either change the CSS rules for `.page-item` or move `.overflay-form` to another container.

Comment: Dude, awesome! Never would have thought of that, I was worried I had to rewrite the javascript :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I had some similar problems when opening a popup which is nested inside an unordered list. Maybe you could try to place your popup html outside the ul?

Anyway, I have always been happy with http://fancybox.net/ which does that popup-things for you. If you haven't heard of this yet, I recommend taking a look at it.